# Sass-loader not resolving import correctly if other type file exists with same name

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, webpack-4, sass-loader

I am using webpack 4 with angular 5 and using sass-loader to convert scss files to css.
I have a scss file (eg main.scss) which imports another scss file eg foo.scss like this:

> @import "foo";

and i also have foo.ts file

sass loader is giving error as it tries to read foo.ts instead of foo.scss while resolving imports from main.scss.

If I assign the unique name to foo.scss file, it will work fine.

Above is the essence of the issue of I am facing, but to be more specific here are details:

The relevant part of my webpack.config file is:

```
{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /(boot\.scss$|node_modules$)/,
      use: [{
              loader: 'to-string-loader'
          },
          {
              loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                  plugins: function() {
                      return [autoprefixer];
                  },
              },
          },
          {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                  includePaths:[path to relevant folder],
              },
          },
      ],
  }
```

Related npm packages with their versions.

> sass-loader@7.0.1  webpack@4.8.3

And Error I am getting is:

> ERROR in ./app/components/alerts/alertlist.component.scss
>   (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--7-3!./app/components/alerts/alertlist.component.scss)
>   Module build failed: import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit,
>   AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
>           ^
>         Property "Directive" must be followed by a ':'
>         in /{path to app}/foo/test-app-animation.ts (line 1, column 10)  @ ./app/components/alerts/alertlist.component.scss 2:21-215  @
>   ./app/components/alerts/alertlist.component.ts  @
>   ./app/components/alerts/module.ts  @ ./app/components/module.ts  @
>   ./app/app.module.ts  @ ./app/index.ts

I have two files in "/{path to app}/foo/" path

> /test-app-animation.ts
>    /test-app-animation.scss

Renaming either of one resolves issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify file extension in your import statement like `import("foo.scss")`, or use unique name for your styles (`foo.styles.scss`) and then import it `import("foo.styles")`.

The point is that, according to [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions), you can skip the an extension that is specified in resolve.extensions array.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: [/* array of extension that are resolved as modules */]
  }
};
```

But if webpack finds a suitable module with some extension, it doesn't check the existence of the files with the rest of extensions.

Comment: I have resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

Comment: Issue triggers when sass-loader try to resolve @import statement from scss files. That made me think that issue is related to resolving import path by sass-loader.
Correct me if I am wrong. PS same resolve extension and same code were working with webpack 3.